# Encrypting A String With Crypto++ (C++) and Decrypting With AESCrypt (Android/java)

Tags: java, android, c++, encryption

I have been working on this for way too long.  At this rate I wont have any hair left.  I have a situation where I am trying to encrypt with c++ and decrypt with java which I thought would be easy with a standard like AES, or so I thought.  Here is the code

The encrypted c++ does not decrypt correctly in the java code.

C++ using crypto++

```
byte key[ CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH ], iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
memset( key, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH );
memset( iv, 0x00, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE );

string plaintext = "this is a test string";
string ciphertext;
string decryptedtext;

CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption( aesEncryption, iv );

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink( ciphertext ) );
stfEncryptor.Put( reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( plaintext.c_str() ), plaintext.length() + 1 );
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

std::cout << "Cipher Text (" << ciphertext() << " bytes)" << std::endl;
```

My  android/java code - 
MainActivity.java

```
            String sEncryptedMsg = "paste encrypted string here from crypto++";
            try {
                String messageAfterDecrypt = AESCrypt.decrypt(password, sEncryptedMsg);
                Log.i("decrypted --> ", messageAfterDecrypt);
            }catch (GeneralSecurityException e){

            }
```

Android/java code - AESCrypt.java

```
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public final class AESCrypt
{


    private static final String TAG = "AESCrypt";

    //AESCrypt-ObjC uses CBC and PKCS7Padding
    private static final String AES_MODE = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

    //AESCrypt-ObjC uses SHA-256 (and so a 256-bit key)
    private static final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";

    //AESCrypt-ObjC uses blank IV (not the best security, but the aim here is compatibility)
    private static final byte[] ivBytes = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    //togglable log option (please turn off in live!)
    public static boolean DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED = false;


    /**
     * Generates SHA256 hash of the password which is used as key
     *
     * @param password used to generated key
     * @return SHA256 of the password
     */
    private static SecretKeySpec generateKey(final String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_ALGORITHM);
        byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        byte[] key = digest.digest();

        log("SHA-256 key ", key);

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        return secretKeySpec;
    }


    /**
     * Encrypt and encode message using 256-bit AES with key generated from password.
     *
     *
     * @param password used to generated key
     * @param message the thing you want to encrypt assumed String UTF-8
     * @return Base64 encoded CipherText
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if problems occur during encryption
     */

    /**
     * Decrypt and decode ciphertext using 256-bit AES with key generated from password
     *
     * @param password used to generated key
     * @param base64EncodedCipherText the encrpyted message encoded with base64
     * @return message in Plain text (String UTF-8)
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if there's an issue decrypting
     */
    public static String decrypt(final String password, String base64EncodedCipherText)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {

        try {
            final SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(password);

            log("base64EncodedCipherText", base64EncodedCipherText);
            byte[] decodedCipherText = Base64.decode(base64EncodedCipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            log("decodedCipherText", decodedCipherText);

            byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypt(key, ivBytes, decodedCipherText);

            log("decryptedBytes", decryptedBytes);
            String message = new String(decryptedBytes, CHARSET);
            log("message", message);


            return message;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
                Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException ", e);

            throw new GeneralSecurityException(e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * More flexible AES decrypt that doesn't encode
     *
     * @param key AES key typically 128, 192 or 256 bit
     * @param iv Initiation Vector
     * @param decodedCipherText in bytes (assumed it's already been decoded)
     * @return Decrypted message cipher text (not encoded)
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if something goes wrong during encryption
     */
    public static byte[] decrypt(final SecretKeySpec key, final byte[] iv, final byte[] decodedCipherText)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedCipherText);

        log("decryptedBytes", decryptedBytes);

        return decryptedBytes;
    }




    private static void log(String what, byte[] bytes) {
        if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
            Log.d(TAG, what + "[" + bytes.length + "] [" + bytesToHex(bytes) + "]");
    }

    private static void log(String what, String value) {
        if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
            Log.d(TAG, what + "[" + value.length() + "] [" + value + "]");
    }


    /**
     * Converts byte array to hexidecimal useful for logging and fault finding
     * @param bytes
     * @return
     */
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        final char[] hexArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    private AESCrypt() {
    }
```

Thanks in advance with any help you can provide!

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The encrypted c++ does not decrypt correctly in the java code. - it comes out garbage

Comment: In what way? Include the specific inputs, keys, and outputs they don't work. If an exception is thrown, include the full stack trace of that exception and point out which line in your code is causing it.

Comment: Are you sure your C++/CryptoPP code does actually Base64 encoding?

Comment: I am not sure.  For sure I am by far a encryption expert and I am open to other libraries as well.  The one thing I cannot change is the C++ does the encryption and java/android does the decryption.

Comment: Also there are no errors, no exceptions, you just make an input string and it comes out as garbage on the java side.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same padding mode in the Java and C++. In the Java code, I see `PKCS7Padding` is explicitly specified, however, I do not see that specified anywhere in the C++ code. (Perhaps I am overlooking something, though.)

Comment: Also, it appears that the `AESCrypt` class is taking in the string password/key, generating a SHA-256 hash of it, and then using that as the key. Whereas, your CryptoPP encryption algorithm seems to be taking in the bytes of the key. This, combined with the padding style, is a significant issue that could certainly explain the huge differences in outputs.